# Custom Latest News Module?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

i'm new to Joomla! but I really like it, i'm working on 'migrating' a website template to Joomla. This is how the template looks like [NerdyFuture](http://nerdyfuture.byethost24.com/). It's not finished yet but i planned on finishing it in Joomla, so i want to have the latest news exactly how it is in the template. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Joomla module **mod_article__latest** can be used as the Latest News module. So once you have your articles setup, you will then need to start the styling.

Step 1 is to create a [template override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for this module. This will allow you to use your own styling for a module without editing any core Joomla files. Here are the steps in simply terms:

1. In your template folder, create a folder called **html** and then inside that, create a folder called **mod_articles_latest**.
2. Copy this file: `modules/mod_articles_latest/tmpl/default.php` to your newly created folder.

Now that you have your file copied, you can start editing it accordingly and merging your styling with it.

Comment: @NerdZilla - If this answered your question fully, please mark it as accepted to other know it has been solved